# C++ How to load from the standard input to an array of chars at most 5 alphanumeric characters?

Tags: c++, arrays

When I load less than 5 chars, it is ok. But if i load more than five chars my program crash.
How can i protect before that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char tab[5];
    int tab2[5];
    char *wsk = tab;
    int i = 0;

    cin >> tab;
    while (true)  {
        cin >> tab2[i];
        if (tab2[i] == 0) break;
        i++;
    }

    i = 0;
    while (true) {
        if (tab2[i] ==0) break;
        wsk += tab2[i];
        cout << *wsk;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (tab2[i] == 0) break;` looks pretty wrong as loop end condition!

Comment: In cases where your memory arrays have hard limits (like 5) you might consider a 'for' loop rather than 'while' loops

Answer (score 2):

You don;t want to limit it to 5.
What you really want is to make sure the read works and never crashes.

The reason you don't want to stop reading at 5 characters is that if the user enters more than 5 characters you have stopped reading in the middle of their input and you now have to write code to find the end of this input and then continue. Writting code to fix the input stream is hard. Rather take input validate (the user may have typed crap and you can generate an error message) but you will be in the correct place to continue reading for the next input operation.

```
char tab[5];
cin >> tab;   // Fails if you read more than 4 input characters
              // (because it will add '\0' on the end)
```

Why not use a self expanding destination structure.

```
std::string tab;
std::cin >> tab;  // Read one word whatever the size.
```

But what about the array.
No more difficult. Here you want an array that re-sizes. Guess what we have std::vector

```
int tab2[5];
while (true)  {
    cin >> tab2[i];  // Fails on the 6 number you input. 
    // STUFF
}
```

The loop can be written like this:

```
std::vector<int> tab2;
while (true)  {
    int val;
    cin >> val;
    tab2.push_back(val); 
    // STUFF
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
while (true)
```

put:

```
while (i < 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard input is a stream. You don't get to decide what's in it. All you can do is read from it and see what you get -- either you get some data, or you learn that the stream has ended.

If you really only want to read five bytes, you can use `std::cin.read(tab, 5)`; you must then call `std::cin.gcount()` to see how many bytes have *actually* been read and only consume as many bytes.

Alternatively, you can use C++'s dynamic containers and use `std::getline(std::cin, line)` to read into an `std::string line` as much data as is available up to a newline.

In either event, you *first* do the reading, *then* check whether and how much you actually read, and *then* check if what you read is of the form you expected (e.g. alphanumeric).

Comment: @0x499602D2: Sorry, that was a typo. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

For C-style arrays, you have to set the width of the input stream to the number of characters allotted to the buffer, otherwise it will be possibly for you to write past the end of the array and get a buffer overflow. This is typically done using [`ios_base::width`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/width):

```
std::cin.width(5);
std::cin >> buffer;
```

You can also use the manipulator [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw):

```
std::cin >> std::setw(5) >> buffer;
```

These will both set the maximum width of the stream to 5 characters. The width will be reset to its default after the first input operation.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition should be

```
while(i < 5)
```

Also a for loop would fit perfectly

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  // body
 }
```

You can use the algorithms part of the STL to bound your reads.
for example :

```
int main(){
    char c[5];
    auto newEnd = std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin), 5, std::begin(c));
    // if newEnd != c + 5 then it failed to read 5 characters

}
```